# Condition number question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Please, help me with this problem:

Let $A$ a matrix of orden $100$,
$$A\ =\ \left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 2 &        &        & \\
  & 1 & 2      &        & \\
  &   & \ddots & \ddots & \\
  &   &        & 1      & 2\\
  &   &        &        & 1
\end{array}\right).$$
Show that $\mbox{cond}_2(A) \geq 2^{99}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Specifically, is your matrix bi-diagonal? We will like to help.

Comment: yes, upper bidiagonal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider a general order $n$. Calculate $\|Ax\|/\|x\|$ with $x=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ to get a lower bound $p=\sqrt{\frac{9(n-1)+1}{n}}$ for $\sigma_1(A)$. Compute $\|Ax\|/\|x\|$ for $x=\left((-2)^{n-1},(-2)^{n-2},\,\ldots,\,-2,1\right)^T$ to get an upper bound $q=\sqrt{\frac{3}{4^n-1}}$ for $\sigma_n(A)$. Now $\frac pq$ is a lower bound for $\operatorname{cond}_2(A)$ and you may show that it is $\ge2^{n-1}$.

Comment: You have $$\mbox{cond}_2(A) \geq \frac{p}{q} = \sqrt{\frac{9(n-1)+1}{n}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{4^n-1}{3}} =\sqrt{\frac{9n\cdot 4^n - 9n -8\cdot 4^n + 8}{3n}}.$$ So, how do you prove that $$\frac{9n\cdot 4^n - 9n -8\cdot 4^n + 8}{3n} \geq 4^{n-1}?$$Thanks

Comment: @FASCH You've made it too complicated. We want to prove that $\frac pq=\frac{p}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{4^n-1}\ge2^{n-1}$ when $n=100$. It suffices to show that $\frac{p}{\sqrt{3}}\ge1$ and $\sqrt{4^n-1}\ge2^{n-1}$ when $n$ is greater than $1$.